# Save a specific variable from a postman array

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

I have a postman json response and within the array the position of a specific variable changes. Based on my response below i need to write a test to loop through the response the first sighting of optionLabel with value "2 Pax Min".
Save its "id" i.e BBBB in the environment variable

I have tried this

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
jsonData[[0].optionSet.options].forEach(function(arroption) { 
if (arroption.optionLabel === '2 Pax Min') {
    pm.environment.set("pax", JSON.stringify(arroption.id));   
}
});
```

My Response

```
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "date": "2019-08-21",
        "optionSet": {
            "optionSetLabel": "Options",
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": "A",
                    "optionLabel": "QUAD Rm"
                },
                {
                    "id": "AA",
                    "optionLabel": "QUAD Rm with post Accom"
                },
                {
                    "id": "AAA",
                    "optionLabel": "Rm 3 Pax Min"
                },
                {
                    "id": "AAAA",
                    "optionLabel": "4 Pax Min"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "date": "2019-08-22",
        "optionSet": {
            "optionSetLabel": "Options",
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": "B",
                    "optionLabel": "QUAD Rm"
                },
                {
                    "id": "BB",
                    "optionLabel": "QUAD Rm with post Accom"
                },
                {
                    "id": "BBB",
                    "optionLabel": "SGL Rm with post Accom"
                },
                {
                    "id": "BBBB",
                    "optionLabel": "2 Pax Min"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

My end result is i want to save the id "BBBB" in the environment variable

Comment: Yes working with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mickael's answer should be the accepted solution (I upvoted it) but I just wanted to offer the same thing done with [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), which is built-in to Postman.

```
_.each(pm.response.json(), (data) => {
    _.each(data.optionSet.options, (option) => {
        if (option.optionLabel === '2 Pax Min') {
            pm.environment.set("pax", option.id);
        }
    })
})
```

I see lots of answers that do this `var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);` to parse the response body but it's the same as just using the newer `pm.*` API function `pm.response.json()` to do the same thing.

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/

Comment: Thanks @Danny Dainton. Your solution worked. Thanks for the info around using just pm instead of what i always do.Might have to fix all my tests. Only issue same as the first solution was it was picking the last id that matched the case instead of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a braket problem here `jsonData[[0].optionSet.options]`.

Maybe you wanted to do something like `jsonData[0].optionSet.options` or `jsonData[1].optionSet.options`

Here this code should do what you want

```js
for (let data of jsonData) {
  for (let option of data.optionSet.options) {
    if (option.optionLabel === '2 Pax Min') {
      pm.environment.set("pax", JSON.stringify(option.id));
    }
  }
}
```

Same with `forEach` rather than `for` loop

```js
jsonData.forEach(function(data) {
  data.optionSet.options.forEach(function(arroption) {
    if (arroption.optionLabel === '2 Pax Min') {
      pm.environment.set("pax", JSON.stringify(arroption.id));
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Mickael B. the second solution worked better for me. Only issue was it was picking the last id that matched the case instead of the first one.